# Need formik values in handle submit outside the formik

Tags: react-native, formik, onsubmit

I have this screen in react native where I want to validate the form and submit it and I have the submit button in my header. How can I get the values in handle submit which is outside the formik. Because I couldn't access the values in the custom function handleSubmit.

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
            navigation.setOptions({
              headerTitleAlign: 'center',
              headerTitle: () => <Text style={styles.titleHeader}>Payment Method</Text>,
              headerRight: () => (
                <Pressable onPress={handleSubmit}>
                  <Text>Done</Text>
                </Pressable>
              ),
            });
          }, [navigation, userId]);

    const handleSubmit = async (values: any) => {
    const data: any = {
      paymentServiceTypeId: defaultPaymentType,
      invoiceNeeded,
      companyName: company,
      vatNumber,
    }
    console.log(values);
  };
         
    return (
            <Formik
              initialValues={initialState}
              onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
              validationSchema={getValidationSchema(staticValues.static)}
            >
              {({ handleChange, handleBlur, values, touched, errors, setFieldValue }) => (
                <>
        {defaultPaymentType == 2 && (
                    <>
                      <Text style={styles.title}>Company Name</Text>
                      <View style={styles.textInputView}>
                        <TextInput
                          style={styles.inputText}
                          placeholder={'Company Name'}
                          value={values.company}
                          onChangeText={handleChange('company')}
                          onBlur={handleBlur('company')}
                        />
                        {touched.company && errors.company && <Text style= 
                          {styles.errorText}>{errors.company}</Text>}
                    <>
                 )}
               </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `const formRef = useRef();` and then

```
<Formik
 ...
 innerRef={formRef} 
/>
```

Now where you need values, get them from `formRef.current.values;`

Answer (score 0):

This issue can easily be fixed by using [useFormik](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) which separates the form from the values and handlers being used by formik. So, even if you have the `submit` button outside the form, you can use the `handleSubmit` provided by the Formik.